# Column name in a dataframe inside a list from lapply

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply

I am transforming this dataframe into a list with separate dataframes

```
df <- data.frame(1:10, 11:20, letters[seq(from=1, to=10)])
colnames(df) <- c(letters[seq(from=1,to=3)])

list.df <- lapply(df[,1:2], function(j) {
  data.frame(j, df$c)
})
```

but I want to set the name the first column name to be the **same** as the name of the list (a and b respectively).
While in this exemple, inside each list, the first column of the dataframe is always "j".

How could I do that???

Also, how could I change the second column from "df.c" to anything else??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the column number and subset the dataframe to get the same name as original column names. Use `cbind` to bind `c` column and assign name of your choice.

```
lapply(1:2, function(i) cbind(df[i], new_name = df$c))

#[[1]]
#    a new_name
#1   1        a
#2   2        b
#3   3        c
#4   4        d
#5   5        e
#6   6        f
#7   7        g
#8   8        h
#9   9        i
#10 10        j

#[[2]]
#    b new_name
#1  11        a
#2  12        b
#3  13        c
#4  14        d
#5  15        e
#6  16        f
#7  17        g
#8  18        h
#9  19        i
#10 20        j
```

Answer (score 0):

we can use `parent.frame()` to get the current column index and set its name;

```
df <- data.frame(1:10, 11:20, letters[seq(from=1, to=10)])
colnames(df) <- c(letters[seq(from=1,to=3)])

list.df <- lapply(df[,1:2], function(j) {
  name_index <- parent.frame()$i
  name_to_set <- colnames(df[,1:2])[name_index] 

  subdf <- data.frame(j,the_name_you_wish = df$c)

  colnames(subdf) <- gsub('j',name_to_set,colnames(subdf))
    
  subdf
  
})
```

also set a new name to `df$c`

output;

```
$a
    a the_name_you_wish
1   1                 a
2   2                 b
3   3                 c
4   4                 d
5   5                 e
6   6                 f
7   7                 g
8   8                 h
9   9                 i
10 10                 j

$b
    b the_name_you_wish
1  11                 a
2  12                 b
3  13                 c
4  14                 d
5  15                 e
6  16                 f
7  17                 g
8  18                 h
9  19                 i
10 20                 j
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
df <- data.frame(1:10, 11:20, letters[seq(from=1, to=10)])
colnames(df) <- c(letters[seq(from=1,to=3)])

library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

list.df <- lapply(1:2, function(j) {
  df %>% select(!!!j, c)
})

list.df
#> [[1]]
#>     a c
#> 1   1 a
#> 2   2 b
#> 3   3 c
#> 4   4 d
#> 5   5 e
#> 6   6 f
#> 7   7 g
#> 8   8 h
#> 9   9 i
#> 10 10 j
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>     b c
#> 1  11 a
#> 2  12 b
#> 3  13 c
#> 4  14 d
#> 5  15 e
#> 6  16 f
#> 7  17 g
#> 8  18 h
#> 9  19 i
#> 10 20 j
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Or if you want to rename

```r
df <- data.frame(1:10, 11:20, letters[seq(from=1, to=10)])
colnames(df) <- c(letters[seq(from=1,to=3)])

library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

list.df <- lapply(1:2, function(j) {
  df %>% select(!!!j, newname = c)
})

list.df
#> [[1]]
#>     a newname
#> 1   1       a
#> 2   2       b
#> 3   3       c
#> 4   4       d
#> 5   5       e
#> 6   6       f
#> 7   7       g
#> 8   8       h
#> 9   9       i
#> 10 10       j
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>     b newname
#> 1  11       a
#> 2  12       b
#> 3  13       c
#> 4  14       d
#> 5  15       e
#> 6  16       f
#> 7  17       g
#> 8  18       h
#> 9  19       i
#> 10 20       j
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>